# Select a previous div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

For the code sample below, when checking the courseID checkbox, I need to check or uncheck the courseGroup checkbox.   The td repeats on the page based on another query higher up.

I tried using:

```
$('.checkedCourse').click(function() {
  if ($(this).closest("td").find('.checkGroup').prop('checked') == true && this.checked == false)
  $(this).closest("td").find('.checkGroup').prop('checked', false); ...
```

But it unchecks all the courseGroup checkboxes on the page and not just the ones for this group.

I also tried `$(this).parents('div:eq(0)')` but I don't know how to get back to more than one `prev()` div.

```
<td colspan="7">
    <cfoutput query="courseData">
        <div name="div1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="courseGroup" class="checkGroup">
            <div class="courseBreak"></div>
            <div class="courseLine">
                <div class="courseSection">#courseSections#</div>
                <div class="courseTitle">#courseTitle#</div>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkedCourse" name="courseID" id="courseID" value="#courseId#">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </cfoutput>
</td>
```

Here's the rendered HTML:
[image: rendered HTML]

I need to have the bolded group (e.g. AMBI 12-13 Sum) unchecked when I unchecked a course in that group

Comment: Are you re-using `id="courseID"`? IDs must be unique.

Comment: Please provide the final rendered html.  It would seem that all of your checkboxes are within the same `td`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, a combination of what you told me works!

```
if ($(this).closest('div[name=courseGrouping]').find('.checkGroup').prop('checked') == true && this.checked == false)
                $(this).closest('div[name=courseGrouping]').find('.checkGroup').prop('checked', false);
```

Now I just have to figure out how to make that top checkbox get checked when everything is checked on the form below it, I'm sure I just have to loop or something.

Answer (score 1):

Since your checkboxes are within the same `td`, you can't use that to find the matching checkbox.  You can however, use the `div` which is a common parent.

```
$(this).closest(".courseLine").closest("div").find('.checkGroup')
```

I would suggest putting a class on that outer `div` to avoid the 2 calls to `closest`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```
if ($(this).closest(".courseLine").prevAll('.checkGroup:first').prop('checked') == true && this.checked == false)
   $(this).closest(".courseLine").prevAll('.checkGroup:first').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: That's not working either
It's not the closest one, it's 2 above

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your IDs are unique, and try this:

```
$('.checkedCourse').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div[name=div1]').find('.checkGroup').prop('checked', !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n46u7/)**